# OBJECT_ID() fails to get object id in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

[print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd1nY.png)[image: print]

I've tried every possible way to get the ID of the object through OBJECT_ID() but it seems like i can only find the object searching it manually in 'sys.objects'. In SQL 2008 it works just fine, same code. I'm using SQL Server 2017 in the picture.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with SQL Server 2014? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object_id('tempdb..#some_name')` will only return a `NOT NULL` result if the temp table was created in the same session.

It looks as though it was created by a different connection.

For your use case (commented out) you can just do

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #some_name
```

Anyway if you are on SQL Server 2017 as stated.

But the screenshot shows 12.0.2000 which is SQL Server 2014 so that won't work on that version.

Comment: Is this new? Because if i create a temp table in one session then use `object_id('tempdb..#some_name')` on another session in SQL Server 2008, it works.

Comment: @italomarca - I haven't got a 2008 instance to test. If it does work that way on 2008 I would call that a bug. There could be multiple possible connections all with a temp table locally named `#some_name`

Comment: >>>if i create a temp table in one session then use object_id('tempdb..#some_name') on another session in SQL Server 2008, it works<<< This means that you created #some_name'in the second session too

Comment: You are right, sorry. I'm using SQL 2014. But yes, it does work on sql 2008... The thing is, even if i try to change my code to `If EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name]  LIKE N'#DebitoCredito[_]%') DROP TABLE #DebitoCredito` it doesn't work. It gives me `Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 13, Cannot drop the table '#DebitoCredito', because it does not exist or you do not have permission`

Comment: Yes because you don't need to worry about temp tables with the same name created in different sessions. You can just use the `object_id` check to verify whether or not it does exist in the current session. If it exists in other sessions it doesn't matter. You can still create it.

Comment: I've got an SQL Server 2008 R2 instance and `object_id()` returns NULL when executed in a different session.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right, the problem is i'm trying to delete a temp table created in another session. I just don't understand why it works with SQL 2008, guess i'll just change my code. But anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: @BaconBits for some reason mine  works, check print 2

Comment: @italomarca that means that temp table was created in the same session.